# Writing a method with ArrayList parameter + for-each loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

Hello amazing people of stackoverflow.

This is my first time posting so I apologize beforehand if I make any mistakes!

The question for this assignment is:

> Write a static method method called longest, which is passed an ArrayList of strings, and which returns the length of the longest string in the array, an int. (Of course several may have the longest value). You MUST use a for-each loop in your solution.

Here's my code:

```
public static int longest(String[] data){

int longString = 0;
for(String s : data)
{
    if (s.length() > longString)
        longString = s.length();
}

return longString;

}
```

I keep getting the general compiler error in the hw submission box - no specifics.
I've looked at my code for an hour and I can't find out what's wrong. Looks good to me :-(

Any and all advice would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to wrap things in a class. If it is wrapped in a class, check whether they require a package declaration.

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: You should not submit your code without even trying to compile it. Compile it, and try to understand the specific error message you get from the compiler. If you don't understand it, post it.

Comment: I agree, you should compile this locally with javac first and then see what errors you get.One hint is that there is no class declaration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code compiles just fine. However, it does not answer the requirement - your method is supposed  to receive an **`ArrayList`**:

```
public static int longest(ArrayList<String> data){

    int longString = 0;
    for(String s : data) {
        if (s.length() > longString)
            longString = s.length();
    }

    return longString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the question requires you to use ArrayList of String instead of an array of Strings.

Try this code:

```
public static int longest(ArrayList<String> data) {

    int longString = 0;
    for (String s : data) {
        if (s.length() > longString)
            longString = s.length();
    }

    return longString;

}
```

**EDIT:**
You'll have to put this code inside a class and have a *main* method for running it.
Your code will then look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LongestString {

    public static int longest(ArrayList<String> data) {

        int longString = 0;
        for (String s : data) {
            if (s.length() > longString)
                longString = s.length();
        }

        return longString;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: It's the length of the string, not the list

Comment: Thank you! The assignment only asked for the method nothing else fortunately.